# What happens with these registry items...?

Tags: windows, windows-registry, regedit

I'm aware that the following registry values relate to the login process, I found in a youtube video that switching out the .bak on the two similar items you can fix a login service error. My question is how does that fix the issue, what is the purpose of the .bak item, and why can't I just delete the one that was giving me an issue entirely?

The video concerned: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vEyxD6ZG-jI

The registry location:

```
HKEY_LOCALMACHINE\
 SOFTWARE\
  Microsoft\
   Windows NT\
    CurrentVersion\
     ProfileList\
      S-1-5-18
      S-1-5-19
      S1-5-21-3428083748234-9230492304-92348923429834-1000
      S1-5-21-3428083748234-9230492304-92348920329834-1000.bak
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just delete it. The video suggests renaming it probably because [this Microsoft KB article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/947215) says to. Under normal circumstances (i.e. when this temporary profile business isn't occurring), Windows won't look at the extra key since it doesn't correspond to any valid SID, so it's not doing anything, but it's not hurting anything either.

The `.bak` is your real entry and was renamed to that when you were signed into a temporary profile, as explained by that KB article. Changing it back to its original name and updating the `RefCount` and `State` makes it loadable again.